# Subset records based on the occurrence of one observation but also additional ones

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following:

> ```
>   ID       Rep    Year     
>  0001      exA    2015
>  0001      exA    2015
>  0002      exA    2015
>  0002      exB    2015
>  0002      exA    2015
>  0002      exC    2015 
>  0003      exC    2016
>  0003      exA    2016
>  0003      exD    2016
>  0003      exA    2016 
> .....     ...    ....
> ```

is there a way to subset IDs based on the appearance of exA in Rep column but also other ex*? This, only for 2015. ID 0001 that has only exA should not be extracted. The criteria is the presence of exA (mandatory) but also other ex*

Desired output:

> ```
>   ID       Rep    Year           
>  0002      exA    2015       
>  0002      exB    2015
>  0002      exA    2015
>  0002      exC    2015
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
input ID $ Rep $ Year;
datalines;
0001 exA 2015 
0001 exA 2015 
0002 exA 2015 
0002 exB 2015 
0002 exA 2015 
0002 exC 2015 
0003 exC 2016 
0003 exA 2016 
0003 exD 2016 
0003 exA 2016 
;

proc sql;
   create table want as
   select * from have
   where year = 2015
   group by ID
   having sum(Rep = 'exA') > 0
      and count(distinct Rep) > 1
   ;
quit;
```